# Automatically add object to array

Tags: php

I have a class called male, which looks like this:

```
class Male {
    public $gender; 
    public $age;
    public $love;
    public $looks;
    public $humor;

    public function __construct ($age , $love , $looks , $humor) {
        $this->gender = 'Male'; 
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->love = $love;
        $this->looks = $looks;
        $this->humor = $humor;
    }
}
```

Everytime there is a new instance of that class like this:

```
$hans = new Male(12 , 45 , 76 , 40);
```

I would like that instance to be automatically added into an array. Right now i do it like this:

```
$maleArray = array($hans);
```

right now i have to do this myself. So lets say i create another instance of my class, then i would have to add this into the maleArray variable. I would like this to go automatically.

for example if i created an instance called herman the new version of maleArray should be :

```
 $maleArray = array($hans, $herman);
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You are not adding it to an array, you are creating a new array with $hans as a entry. You want to initalizie the array outside, `$mayArray  = [];` and append to that array via: `$myArray[] = $hans;`. You should know how many objects you need to initalize and then it becomes a matter of creating a loop over that range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the `[]` to automatically add an occurance to an array

```
$maleArray[] = new Male(12 , 45 , 76 , 40);
```